# Image won't resize properly, it constantly changes the general focal point/center point

Tags: css, image

I'm working on a project for a friend as my first little css/html based "project" and I'm having a problem with the image on the bottom, if you resize it, it constantly changes the general focal point, how do I go about it not doing that.

If I make it smaller, more of the photo will show, if I make it bigger less and less will show. (Referring to resizing the browser)

https://codepen.io/Salt_Salt/pen/rNeNYyo

```css
<style>
.text{
  font-family: "Sofia";
}

#scrollingbar{
  text-align :center;
  border: 15px solid black;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: hotpink;
  
}

#text1{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  bottom: 10vh;
}

#entreephoto{
  text-align: center;
  border: 15px solid black;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: hotpink;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: reletive;
}

#entreephoto > img{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -5vh;
  margin-left: -28vh;
}

.bottomphoto{
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 15px solid black;
  padding:0px;
  height:60vh;
  width:100vw;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}

.photos> img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0vh;
  top:  -100vh;
}

#text2{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: -3.5vw;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

img{
  max-width:100%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia'>
  </head>
  <heading>
  <div id="scrollingbar">
       <img src = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/651540333125173262/741233047487250463/rra.png" width="10%" height= "auto">
    <div id=text1 class="text">
        Welcome to my page
    </div>
      <img src = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/651540333125173262/741233047487250463/rra.png" width="10%" height= "auto">
    </div>
</heading>
  <body>
    <div id="entreephoto">
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/651540333125173262/741232172987449374/2548.png" height="60%" width="auto%">
      <div id=text2 class="text">
        Some tongue just for you
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomphoto">
      <div class="photos">
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/658376744637562880/740589629182443570/1080-3486.png" width="100%" height="auto">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to always entirely show in your div, you should add `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`

It should look something like this:

```css
.bottomphoto {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 15px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.bottomphoto>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomphoto">
  <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/658376744637562880/740589629182443570/1080-3486.png">
</div>
```

Though, at large widths, image will stretch out too much and will look really bad. Another approach would be to resize div along with the image

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bottomphoto{
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 15px solid black;
}

.bottomphoto > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomphoto">
  <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/658376744637562880/740589629182443570/1080-3486.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Though I'm looking to keep the focal point around the eys/head, when I do that it resizes and slowly moves from the head, how do I fix that?

Comment: @Trey I don't really understand what do you mean by that.

Comment: When you resize the photo (Aka, how it responds to being resized), It'll slowly show more and more of the photo, or less and less. How do I stop it from showing more or less and just have the photo be static when resized inside the div, as in the same view/amount is shown on resize.

Answer (score -1):

Download the photo first, do not link to it
second give class to youre image

and then give styl

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider reading article on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Telling "and then give style" doesn't really help. Instead, you should tell what style they should add based on their question